# Links between meta.photo and photo seem to be broken.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The links between meta.photo and photo both point to http://stackexchange.com for me at the moment.  Styling also seems off (background texture/colours are off).

Edit: and now the link is a StackExchange logo.  Maybe I've just caught it in the middle of a change-over or had a caching blip.

But what happened to the 'visit parent/meta' links?

Comment: Tech details just in case: Chrome 5.0.375.125, OSX 10.5.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent/meta links are now on the right, between logout and about links. Shift+refresh might help if you don't see them yet.

To be honest, in the previous layout, there was much more probability somebody clicking the meta link:)

Comment: No kidding about the previous layout. They're hidden over there.

Comment: Meta is also linked in the footer of the main site to here, too

Comment: The previous image link also gave some indication about "meta" being "more stuff of some kind". This does not. Lots of people have no idea what meta means (those unfamiliar with the Stack Overflow model), so the link will have very poor information scent for them. Frankly, I think the new meta link is much worse. I'm sure the log data will show dramatically less flow from the main site to meta, especially for new users.